# Magento 2 Reset Modify FROM select query

Tags: collection, magento2.2.2, query, select, reset-filter

How can one modify the `FROM` in select query without losing the `left joins` `innerJoin` etc... ? as I have tried:

`$collection->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::FROM)->from('table_2')` but then I've lost all the `leftjoin` `concat`  etc...

Thanks

Comment: As you using reset on from then leftjoin will be lost. You have to add all of them again

Comment: @AmitBera crap that's not quite what I expected it would do but it is what it is!

Comment: @AmitBera I must have been doing something wrong check out my answer it works!

Comment: thanks.i was wrong . Thanks for correction

Answer (score 2):

This works for me :

```
->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::FROM)->from(array('main_table' => 'table_2'));
```

I think I was doing something wrong as the above also needs the alias set and now it works!.

Comment: You have to add table_2 alise.greats. New thing, i learn :)